# I made a disastrous mistake with "create git repo here" - how do I rectify/undo it?

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am new to Git. I have created an account on Bitbucket and downloaded TortoiseGit.

I'm on Windows 7 and on the desktop I right clicked and thought "add git repo here" would create an empty folder that could be committed, but iy turns out it has **staged ** every folder on the desktop to be committed to master instead.

How do I undo this?

Comment: isn't that going to delete the files? I might be asking a dumb question but I have some important stuff here hence asking.

Comment: I tried doing that just now. I still see "Desktop" marked with a green check symbol.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to turn on `Show hidden files` in Explorer. Then delete `.git` directory in your desktop

Answer (score 1):

Do not run `git reset --hard` that will delete all the files. Delete the hidden .git folder.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> type in `cmd` and press enter.

```
cd Desktop
rmdir /S .git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
git reset HEAD *
```

It would unstage all of your files and none of your changes will go away.

Answer (score 0):

With TortoiseGit 1.8.7.1, a warning message will be added when creating repository on special folders, such as Desktop, drive root, UNC root, User Profile, Windows Directory, system32, Program Files

The Create Repository menu item may be clicked by mistake.

[image: Warning]

Comment: Let's try TortoiseGit 1.8.7.1 preview