# TortoiseGit - undo create repository here

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I stupidly clicked *Git Create Repository here* inside of my SSH folder where my public key was. Now all of my folders have this small blue question mark next to them, and I can no longer successfully clone a repository. I'm getting an error every time.

What do I do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323884/made-a-disastrous-mistake-with-create-git-repo-here-how-to-rectify-undo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enable the options to see hidden folders in Windows Explorer and then delete the .git folder.